# How can I get the latest VLC if its not available from the VLC download page and its PPA

Tags: apt, software-installation, ppa, vlc

The latest [vlc(2.1)](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/releases/2.1.0.html) had just been released - jeej - but, the [vlc-ppa](https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/stable-daily) doesn't contain packages for 13.04 only 13.10. The [vlc download page](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html) just says to `sudo apt-get install vlc`.

> 2.1.0 Highlights
>
> With a new audio core, hardware decoding and encoding, port to mobile
>   platforms, preparation for Ultra-HD video and a special care to
>   support more formats, 2.1 is a major upgrade for VLC.
>
> Rincewind has a new rendering pipeline for audio, with better
>   effiency, volume and device management, to improve VLC audio support.
>
> It supports many new devices inputs, formats, metadata and improves
>   most of the current ones, preparing for the next-gen codecs.
>
> Rincewind fixes around a thousand bugs, in more than 7000 commits from
>   140 volunteers.

How can I get the latest vlc, if it's not available from the vlc download page or the PPA?

Comment: On another note, why do you need the newest release? Does it have a feature that you really need and can't wait for?

Comment: its, its stability that i want. It has over a thousand bug fixes. of course there are some new stuff that also looks very interesting

Comment: In the majority of cases packages managed by the distro are more stable than external ones.

Comment: ah but it will also have 1000 NEW bugs. The one Ubuntu currently has is the most stable for Ubuntu. I answered the question but me too would suggest to stick with the current one -unless- you experience one of the fixed bugs and need it fixed. If it seems not broken why try to fix it ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind, while this maybe true. I due experienced some bugs with vlc, that are the same in the Ubuntu repos. I'll check the latest vlc for the same bug(s), if it is the same, I'll search for bug reports if its ongoing. if not I'll report it in great details myself.

Comment: one core feature of the new VLC release is that it comes with VDPAU support on Linux. That means full hardware acceleration on both Nvidia (proprietary blob) and AMD (newest radeon drivers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install it from source as soon as these are updated.

Start here: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-sources.html

> **How to compile?**
>
> Please have a look at VLC's sub-page on the [developers website](http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc.html). There are detailed descriptions for most systems, supported by VLC. If something is not mentioned there, searching the [forum](http://forum.videolan.org/) is worth a try.

---

From [developers website](http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc.html):

> **Get VLC Source Code**
>
> VLC is available through [Git](http://wiki.videolan.org/Git) or by browsing the [releases](http://www.videolan.org/pub/vlc/).
>
> You can also see the release notes and the ChangeLog. You can also give an eye on the ["Get the source" wiki page](http://wiki.videolan.org/GetTheSource).

---

The source for VLC [2.1 can be found here](http://download.videolan.org/pub/vlc/2.1.0/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install the packages for 13.10 manually and see, if that works. Otherwise, compile it from source.

Answer (score 0):

You linked the [stable VLC PPA](https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/stable-daily) in your answer but there's also a PPA of the master branch which  offers the [latest development builds for all Ubuntu releases](https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/master-daily). This is currently `2.2.0~~git20130926` which should include all 2.1 features.

I am pretty confident though that VLC 2.1 is soon to arrive in the stable PPA. There is no discernible reason why it shouldn't if the newest dev builds are already offered for all Ubuntu releases 12.04 and up.